# How to initialize an Intent in a fragment class

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

Im trying to put up this code in my fragment class :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
         Intent haha = new Intent(ProfileFragment.this, Portal.class);
}
```

but it just keep saying that **"the constructor Intent(ProfileFragment, Class) is Undefined"**.
i am pretty sure that i have this Class Portal in my java classes.

Comment: Use getActivity() in stead of ProfileFragment.this

Comment: OO nga, try using getActivity()

Comment: yes i got it, tnx guys. salamat :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize ike this..

```
Intent haha = new Intent(getActivity(), Portal.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Intent haha = new Intent(getActivity(), Portal.class);
}
```